# Possible to flush out pre-existing schema types?

Tags: shopify

I am attempting to completely rewrite footer.liquid. Unfortunately, there are pre-existing fields which I am no longer using which are causing errors to be thrown when I attempt to save my file. For example:

- Error: New schema is incompatible with the current setting value. Invalid type value for block 'linklist'. Type must be defined in schema.

I understand that this is because I am not using an "id": "linklist" in my new schema. Is there a way to flush out these pre-existing schema types so that I don't have to include it in my schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete the section in the theme editor and then readd the section after, that should solve the problem.

Alternatively, you could find the **settings_data.json** and remove the current values associated with your footer section.

Comment: I wasn't aware of either of these methods. Thank you very much, Ty.

Comment: No problem! If you have an issue with that, let me know.